# Change chips color on checkbox change materialize css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I have searched online and I couldn't get a solution to my problem.

I am working with materialize css chips, what I want is that whenever the checkbox is checked, the color of the last chip should change to green and others to red, when unchecked,they all turn red.

I don't know if this is possible as I have set my conditions already

```
$('.chips-placeholder').chips({
    placeholder: 'Enter options',
    secondaryPlaceholder: '+Options',
    limit:6
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#anscheck').change(function() {
        if($("#anscheck").is(":checked")){

        }    
    });
});
```

html

```
                   <div class="row opt">
                       <div class="col m4 s10 offset-m3 chips-placeholder">
                           <input type="text" name="opts[]">
                       </div>
                       <div class="col m4 s10 switch correctans">
                        <label>
                          Off
                          <input type="checkbox" id='anscheck'>
                          <span class="lever"></span>
                          On
                        </label>
                       </div>
                   </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the HTML please?

Comment: @Scoots yeah sure, done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Set `onChipAdd` and `onChipDelete` events to change the color when adding or deleting a chip.

I would initialize the chip component without jQuery method.

1) Get all of the chips.

`$(chipInstance[0].$chips)`

2) Loop through all the chips and check if the (index+1) of the chip equals the number of all chips. (Cause index is zero-based.)

```
allChips.each(function(index, element){
  let Color = (index+1) == allChips.length ? 'green' : 'red';
  $(element).addClass(Color)
})
```

3) Add class to change the font color.

Here's a demo:

```js
let target = $('.chips-placeholder');
let options = {
  placeholder: 'Enter options',
  secondaryPlaceholder: '+Options',
  limit: 6,
  onChipAdd: function(){
    CheckChipsColor();
  },
  onChipDelete: function(){
    CheckChipsColor();
  }
}

let chipInstance = M.Chips.init(target, options)

$('#anscheck').change(function() {
  CheckChipsColor();
});

function CheckChipsColor(){
  let allChips = $(chipInstance[0].$chips);
  allChips.removeClass('red green');
  if ($("#anscheck").is(":checked")) {
    allChips.each(function(index, element){
      let Color = (index+1) == allChips.length ? 'green' : 'red';
      $(element).addClass(Color)
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}

.green{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.js"></script>

<div class="row opt">
  <div class="col m4 s10 offset-m3 chips-placeholder">
    <input type="text" name="opts[]">
  </div>
  <div class="col m4 s10 switch correctans">
    <label>
    Off
      <input type="checkbox" id='anscheck'>
      <span class="lever"></span>
    On
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You just saved my life and that of others who would need something similar to this! However, I noticed after the checkbox is checked, and I type in another chips, the last entered chips doesn't turn green. I have to un-check and check the checkbox again for it to turn green. Could you please help with that too? P.S: It's not really important but for user's experience. Also I love the way you explained this in details.